# Symfony2 forms with many to many through

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on some project with excellent symfony2 framework and I'm stack with some problem.

I have to implement these entities:

```
User
System
Partner
```

User entity is a kind of customer and in the registration form it should be able to choose own Partner but only one for each type of system. For example one partner for Windows system, one for DOS and one for Mac OSX.

So, the form should have some standard fields like email, password and (for me the following is very important) 3 dropdowns with lists of available partners (one dropdown for each of the system).

In this article http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html I found that if I want to implement this kind of association I have to make third entity for additional fields in my app between User and Partner, and it works but not quite with my System restriction.

I think the relation should looks like this:

```
User one-to-many System
Partner one-to-many System
```

The problem is how to make these 3 dropdowns, one for each system in the symfony and doctrine way?

Comment: Mmmmh I think you more need `User one-to-many System many-to-one Partner`. What would you need a third table `UserPartnerRelation` for?

Comment: You right... thanks, but what if I want to save the time when the user was linked with partner?

Comment: Then you could add a column `created` (typed DateTime) part of the middle table (here `System`) and set it to `now` in this entity constructor. That's if I understand well your problem... :)

Comment: Hmmm with current relation approach I have entity System which has 4 column: id, name, user_id, partner_id. The problem is how to prevent duplicates system name for each linked User - Partner? This is the reason why I had third entity UserPartnerRelation with columns: id, user_id, partner_id and system_id